# using RestKit un-restfully

Tags: ios, api, restkit

Is there any way to use RestKit in an unrestful way?

For example, If I set up an object mapping as such:

```
[manager.router routeClass:[BBMediaResourceCreate class] 
            toResourcePath:@"/mediaresources" 
                 forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

RestKit will expect that I post a BBMediaResourceCreate object and receive one back also.

My API however, for reasons I won't go into, is not RESTful compliant in some situations. Rather than receive the newly created resource, I'll get something more like:

```
{ Model: { Success:true} }
```

or something similar

Is there a way to map a RestKit post to post a resource of one type but expect a response of another type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using v0.10 you can simply set `resourcePath:@"/"`and respond to

`- (void)objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader`

or

`- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object`

and handle the response in `[objectLoader response]` like you want. Keep in mind that posting to that resource then needs an explicit, manually set path.